# Normalizing rows of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need to normalize the rows of a dataframe containing rows populated with all zero. For example:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({"ID": ['1', '2', '3', '4'], "A": [1, 0, 10, 0], "B": [4, 0, 30, 0]})

ID  A   B
1   1   4
2   0   0
3   10  30
4   0   0
```

My approach is to first exclude the zero-value rows followed by normalizing the non-zero subset using:

```
df1 = df[df.sum(axis=1) != 0]
df2 = df[df.sum(axis=1) == 0]
sum_row = df1.sum(axis=1)
df1.div(sum_row, axis=0)
```

and then concatenate the two dataframes as follows:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]).reset_index()
```

However, I end up with the following error while applying `df1.div(sum_row, axis=0)`

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,)
>   (2,)

I wonder how to fix the error and if there exists a more efficient approach. Thanks!

Edit: The resulting dataframe is expected to look like as:

```
ID  A     B
1   0.2   0.8 
2   0     0
3   0.25  0.75
4   0     0
```

Comment: Could you add the excepted results, please?

Comment: @AnnaIliukovich-Strakovskaia Done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [div](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html):

```
df= pd.DataFrame({"ID": ['1', '2', '3', '4'], "A": [1, 0, 10, 0], "B": [4, 0, 30, 0]})
df.set_index("ID", inplace=True)
df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Normalizer in scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer.html)

```
df= pd.DataFrame({"ID": ['1', '2', '3', '4'], "A": [1, 0, 10, 0], "B": [4, 0, 30, 0]})
df = df.set_index('ID')

from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
df.iloc[:,:] = Normalizer(norm='l1').fit_transform(df)

print(df)

       A     B
ID            
1   0.20  0.80
2   0.00  0.00
3   0.25  0.75
4   0.00  0.00
```

Comment: This is great because you can easily change the norm used.  In my case, I see so many examples of the l1 norm on SO, whereas I need to normalize each row according to l2 for my current needs.

Answer (score 1):

Using `melt` with `crosstab`

```
newdf=df.melt('ID')
pd.crosstab(index=newdf.ID,columns=newdf.variable,values=newdf.value,normalize='index',aggfunc='mean')
Out[447]: 
variable     A     B
ID                  
1         0.20  0.80
2         0.00  0.00
3         0.25  0.75
4         0.00  0.00
```